# Sbt Resolvers to not contain scala version on app name

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager, resolver, sbt-web

Currently I have an issue using the sbt resolvers to find my project.

I am currently publishing my project to

```
https://artifacts.placeholder.io/artifactory/release-local/com/placeholder/app/placeholder-app/2.15.26/placeholder-app-2.15.26.pom
```

I have set crossPaths := false in the publishSettings

However this is my resolver

```
  artifactoryRPARelease = "Release" at "https://artifacts.placeholder.io/artifactory/release-local"
```

but it tries to look for my published project here

```
https://artifacts.placeholder.io/artifactory/release-local/com/placeholder/app/placeholder-app_2.11/2.15.26/placeholder-app_2.11-2.15.26.pom
```

Is there a way to make it so the resolver has some sort of crossPath = false? or a way to get rid of the scala version "_2.11" at the end of the app name?

Comment: Did you try with `crossPaths := false`?

Comment: does crossPaths := false work on resolvers?